# Creating a new instance of a KClass

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have a Kotlin class whose primary (and only) constructor is empty.

I have a reference to this class:

```
val kClass: KClass<MyClass> = MyClass::class
```

How do I create an instance of this class using reflection?

In Java I would do `myClass.newInstance()` but it seems in Kotlin I need to find the constructor first:

```
kClass.constructors.first().call()
```

I have seen mention of `primaryConstructor` in [some bug reports](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6728) but it's not showing up in my IDE.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your case, Java reflection might be enough: you can use `MyClass::class.java` and create a new instance in the same way as you would with Java reflection (see [@IngoKegel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936832/ingo-kegel)'s answer).

But in case there's more than one constructor and you really need to get the primary one (not the default no-arg one), use the [`primaryConstructor`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/primary-constructor.html) extension function of a [`KClass<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html). It is a part of [Kotlin reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html), which is not shipped within `kotlin-stdlib`.

To use it, you have to add [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) as a dependency, e.g. a in Gradle project:

```
dependencies {
     compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"    
}
```

<sup>Assuming that there is  `ext.kotlin_version`, otherwise replace `$kotlin_version` with the version you use.</sup>

Then you will be able to use `primaryConstructor`, for example:

```
fun <T : Any> construct(kClass: KClass<T>): T? {
    val ctor = kClass.primaryConstructor
    return if (ctor != null && ctor.parameters.isEmpty())
        ctor.call() else
        null
}
```

Comment: if constructor need parameters, the above way is useless

Comment: if constructor needs parameters, what's the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 32):

You can use the Java class to create new instance:

```
MyClass::class.java.newInstance()
```

Comment: Really interesting that Kotlin doesn't have a similarly simple and idiomatic way of doing this

Comment: Btw, `Class.newInstance()` is deprecated since Java 9 with the argument that is bypassed checked exceptions.

Comment: This will fail on Data classes unless constructor is manually created

Answer (score 16):

For those checking this question now, since Kotlin 1.1 there's also `createInstance()` extension method on `KClass`

Much like the accepted answer, this function works only in case class has an empty constructor or constructor with all default arguments.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html

Comment: Underrated answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't understand how to use createInstance passing parameters. How?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Alexeys Answer, to include a primary constructor call with parameters:

```
/* Example class with no-args constructor */
class MyClass

/* Example class requiring parameters */
class MyClassWithParams(parameter1: String, parameter2: MyClass)

val myKClass: KClass<MyClass> = MyClass::class
val myKClassWithParameters: KClass<MyClassWithParams> = MyClassWithParams::class

/* We can create an object by calling createInstance when no constructor parameters are required as explained in other answers. */
val myObject: MyClass = myKClass.createInstance()

/* To create an object with parameters, we need to get the constructor first, and call it with the parameters instead, similarly to how we would do in Java. */
val myObjectWithParameters: MyClassWithParams? = 
myKClassWithParameters.primaryConstructor?.call(
    "StringParameter", myObject
)
```

Comment: Straight to the point. Thanks for sharing this :)

Answer (score 1):

I liked hotkey's answer but I couldn't get his primaryConstructor code example to work.  I did get the following code to work:

```
    fun <T : Any> construct(kClass: KClass<T>): T? {
      val constructors = kClass.constructors
      for (constructor in constructors) {
           if (constructor.parameters.size == 0) return constructor.call()
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: This answer was part of my earlier days of learning kotlin.  What I didn't understand at the time was that all KClass'es don't necessarily have a primaryConstructor.  It all depends on how you define the class on whether the class has a primaryConstructor of not.  I was under the assumption that if you define a class without any constructors then the constructor without any parameters was the primaryConstructor, but that's not the case.  That explains why I couldn't get hotkey's code to work for me and why the code above worked for me in my situation.